Node version incompatible with Astro
I am exploring Astro and have ran the recommended code to try out their pre-built blog. The code entered into terminal is:
npm create astro@latest -- --template blog

error is:
Node.js v18.3.0 is not supported by Astro!
Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version: ">=18.14.1"

I was expecting it to work, given it's just a standard npm install script. Not sure why this is happening. Anyone had a similar issue?

For node package it can be specified which node version is required (if the package uses features that are only present in that version). And that’s what happened in your case.

@t.niese even though 18.3 is greater than 18.14.1, I need to specify to use a lower version?

18.3 is not greater then 18.14 (it is 3 < 14).

I would recommend upgrading to the latest Node.js LTS (currently v20.13). If you need different Node.js versions for different projects, I can recommend https://volta.sh
